# Is there a way to limit the number of File Handler instances?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a component which uses the spring framework File integration to kick off a process each time a file arrives at a location. I can see from log files that two threads/processes/instances are running. Is there a way to limit it to one?

The second process/thread appears to kick off almost immediately after the first and they are interfering with each other. The first instance processes the file but then the second tries to do the same and hits a filenotfound exception because the first moved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to consider to configure a poller for your file inbound channel adapter with the `fixedDelay` instead of `fixedRate`. This way the next polling task is not going to be start until the end of the previous one.

Also consider to use some `filter` do not process the same file again. Not sure what is your use-case , but simple `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` should be enough. There is a `prevent-duplicates` option on the channel adapter for convenience.

See more info in the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#files

And also about the poller behavior: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#channel-adapter-namespace-inbound